# Need to span my <td> across several rows, not working, using Razor syntax

Tags: html, css, razor

Here's my code (look where it says `rowspan="6"` - this is what is not working:

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ingredient</td>
                        <td>Qty (gm)</td>
                        <td>% of Capsule</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDecimal(i.Qty) < 0)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid red; color: red;">@i.Ingredient</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid red; color: red;">@i.Qty</td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(i.Qty) == 0m)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (i.Ingredient.Contains("Active"))
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@i.Ingredient<br />
                                <input type="text" name="@i.Ingredient" id="@i.Ingredient" /></td>
                            <td>@i.Qty</td>
                            @if (i.Percent != 0m)
                            {
                                <td rowspan="6" style="text-align: center;">@i.Percent.ToString("#.##")</td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@i.Ingredient</td>
                            <td>@i.Qty</td>
                            @if (i.Percent != 0m)
                            {
                                <td style="text-align: center;">@i.Percent.ToString("#.##")</td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td></td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Total %:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Model.Sum(j => j.Percent).ToString("#.##")</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Which produces:

[image]

I need to align the cell that contains 9.74 to the center of the 6 rows, as indicated in the screenshot with the red arrows.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The rowspan is working fine. The value just needs to be vertically aligned,

```
<td rowspan="6" style="vertical-align:center; text-align:center;">
```

Let me know if this helps.